# Issue in event.PreventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap in my application. i gave **e.preventDefault for  link button in $(document).ready()**, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

Master page:

```
<a id="lnkLogout" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PageLogout();"><i class="icon-off"></i>Logout</a>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogout" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" runat="server" class="hidden" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lnkLogout').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });         
    });  
    function PageLogout() {
        $("#btnLogout").click();
    }                
</script>
```

MasterPage.aspx.cs :

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Response.Redirect("~/SampleWindowCloser.htm");            
}
```

SampleDefaultPage.aspx :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="form-horizontal">
          <h4 class="header blue bolder smaller">
              Contact</h4>
          <div class="control-group">
              <label for="form-field-email" class="control-label">
                    Email</label>
              <div class="controls">
                   <input type="text" style="width:200px;" data-val="true" 
                           data-val-required="Mobile Number is required."  
                           id="txtEmail">
                   <div class="space-3">
                   </div>
                   <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="txtEmail" 
                         class="field-validation-valid text-warning red"></span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
               <label for="form-field-website" class="control-label">
                      Phone Number</label>
               <div class="controls">
               <input type="text" style="width:200px;" 
                      id="txtPhno">                             
         </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

I have given **txtEmail** as mandatory field. if i left that field blank and click on Logout button in Master page, it says **txtEmail is required**. i dint do any validation in  Logout onclick event. I have given preventDefault for Logout link. But still facing an issue. **I should be able to logout even though txtEmail is left blank**.

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Comment: calling the prevent default on the anchor element does not prevent the inline `onclick` handler from being fired, I guess the validation is done in that method

Comment: Why can't you move the inlined click handler `onclick="PageLogout();"` to a jQuery click handler

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `return false`?

```
  <a id="lnkLogout" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PageLogout(); return false;">
```

Or putting `PageLogout()` inside the `Click()` event handler along with the `e.preventDefault()` inside:

```
<a id="lnkLogout" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-off">
                        </i>Logout</a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#lnkLogout').click(
   function PageLogout(e) {
         // more code here
         e.preventDefault(); });         
    });  
</script>
```

See [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZJtL/)

Comment: last scenario moved `PageLogout()` inside a closure....will throw errors not being defined now. That definitely doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lnkLogout').click(function (e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       // code for logout from application
    });         
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <a id="lnkLogout" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-off"></i>Logout</a>
```

**Updated**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lnkLogout').click(function (e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       $("#btnLogout").click();
    });         
});
```